# Making exported excel sheet as readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application i'm exporting gridview data to excel and storing it to a particular folder now what i want is to make this excel file as read only so that no one should edit it.

i have written code like this:

protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

```
        this.GridView1.Page.EnableViewState = false;
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        hw.WriteLine("<b><font size='5'> Report</font></b>");
        this.GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        string HtmlInfo = tw.ToString();
        string DocFileName = "Report" + ".xls";
        string FilePathName = Request.PhysicalPath;
        FilePathName = FilePathName.Substring(0, FilePathName.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        FilePathName = @"C:\Excel" + "\\" + DocFileName;
        FileStream Fs = new FileStream(FilePathName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter BWriter = new BinaryWriter(Fs,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        BWriter.Write(HtmlInfo);
        BWriter.Close();
        Fs.Close();

   }
```

any1 help me on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make the file readonly after it's been written?

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(FilePathName );
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = true;
```

**EDIT**

This is for a website? I don't know of a way you can prevent someone from downloading then modifying your file.  You could use an API to do it instead.   We use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) here to make Sheets readonly before sending them to the client.

Comment: @Jeff-i have created folder in my local machine and i'm saving this excel sheet there now what i want is that it should not be editable how can i do that..

Comment: Using fileinfo works on my machine.  Are you getting some kind of exception?

Comment: @Jeff-no i'm not getting any exception but the excel file can be editable i dont want that to happen the user should not be able to edit it..if i remove filestream and binary writer it throwing error like this Could not find file 'C:\Excel\Report.xls'.

Comment: Don't really know what to tell you, works fine here.  I double checked it, and I see the readonly flag changing on the file.

Comment: That IS the complete code.   After you've written the file out and closed the stream, that code flips it to readonly.   There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have something like

```
 FileStream Fs = new FileStream(FilePathName, FileMode.Create, Fileaccess.Read);
```

See this link for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx#Y494

Comment: @Dean-its throewing error like this Server Error in '/WebSite31' Application.
Combining FileMode: Create with FileAccess: Read is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You cant do both work together first u have to create file stream and than define it's access mode

Have a look on this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx